# How can we get value from future method in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, global-variables, sharedpreferences

I have this function returning the "SharedPreference" value stored in it.

```dart
  Future<bool> getLoginStatus() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final loggedInStatus = prefs.getBool("loggedInStatus");

    if (loggedInStatus == null) {
      return false;
    }
    return loggedInStatus;
  }
```

Above function is in the class named "Constants.dart". When I do the test of extracting value from "getLoginStatus()" function by simple printing in different class.

```dart
 print("Login status : " + Constants().getLoginStatus().toString());
```

It give me below as an output. Why "Instance of 'Future'"? Why not simple either true or false?

```dart
I/flutter (19683): Login status : Instance of 'Future<bool>'
```

Comment: I can recommend reading about asynchronous programming in Dart: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your getLoginStatus() is asynchronous and it return a bool value in future. So to get the value you have to await for the process to return it.

So the correct Code to retrieve the value would be :

```
bool loggedInStatus = await Constants().getLoginStatus();
print(loggedInStatus);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
getLoginStatus().then((val){ print("Login status : $val"});
```

The then function should be used with Futures to access the value returned from a future.

Answer (score 1):

you can get data using await.

```
var data  = await Constants().getLoginStatus();
print(data);
```